# JavaScript Array JSON.parse (string)

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, echarts

I am using eCharts (a JavaScript charting library) and there is something that's doing my head in. The examples use the following code for markLine (and it works as expected)

```
markLine : {
    symbol: 'none',
    tooltip: {show: false},
    itemStyle:{
        normal:{
            lineStyle:{
                type: 'solid',
                color: '#CCCCCC'
            },
            tooltip:{
                show: false
            }
        }
    },
    data: [ [{ "xAxis" : 250, "yAxis" : 0 }, {"xAxis": 250, "yAxis" : 250 }] ]
}
```

I need to be able to get the data part as a JSON string, but I cannot get it to work. 
*Note: For simplicity, I have the same JSON information I receive as a string called arrayString*:

```
markLine : {
    symbol: 'none',
    tooltip: {show: false},
    itemStyle:{
        normal:{
            lineStyle:{
                type: 'solid',
                color: '#CCCCCC'
            },
            tooltip:{
                show: false
            }
        }
    },
    data: (function (){
        var res = [];
        var arrayString = "";

        arrayString = '[{ "xAxis" : 250, "yAxis" : 0 }, {"xAxis": 250, "yAxis" : 250 }]';
        res = JSON.parse(arrayString);

        return res;
    })()
}
```

When I run the JSON.parse code the chart doesn't display, but if I console.log the value of 'res' the array appears to be created correctly.

Is anyone able to assist me with resolving this?

References:
Both of these examples use markLine:
http://echarts.baidu.com/echarts2/doc/example/line1.html#-en 
http://echarts.baidu.com/echarts2/doc/example/bar13.html#-en

Comment: Should these be two objects within an array within another array (like in the first snippet), or just two objects within an array (like in the second snippet)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should you be adding to your res array rather than overwiting it?

```
res.push(JSON.parse(arrayString));
```

Comment: Perfect - I knew it would be something simple. I must have been looking at this for the better part of an hour now going crazy.

Comment: @Glen we have most definitely all been there.